# Can we create parquet table from existing?

Tags: hive, parquet

I have a table with huge data.
I have to fetch a few columns from it and create a parquet table.
The below is what I did-

```
CREATE TABLE parqfiletable
AS
SELECT col2, col4, col8 FROM txtfiletable
STORED AS PARQUET;
```

This is succeeded, however when I am trying to retrieve the data from parquet table, it is throwing an error.

Moreover, the same create table statement not working now.

I would have done it in a normal way like creating a table definition stored as parquet and then load the data from the original source. But the above worked instantly on that time and the table was created.

Could you please make me understand what's wrong with the create table statement?
Can't we create 'CREATE AS .. STORED AS PARQUET'?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE parqtab
AS
SELECT col2, FROM txtfiletable
AS PARQUET;
```

This way we can create it but this isn't a PARQUET table as per the extended properties.

```
Detailed Table Information  Table(tableName:parqtab, dbName:dbtest, owner:cloudera, createTime:1606338549, lastAccessTime:0, retention:0, sd:StorageDescriptor(cols:[FieldSchema(name:col2, type:string, comment:null)], location:hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/dbtest.db/parqtab, inputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat, outputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat, compressed:false, numBuckets:-1, serdeInfo:SerDeInfo(name:null, serializationLib:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, parameters:{serialization.format=1}), bucketCols:[], sortCols:[], parameters:{}, skewedInfo:SkewedInfo(skewedColNames:[], skewedColValues:[], skewedColValueLocationMaps:{}), storedAsSubDirectories:false), partitionKeys:[], parameters:{numFiles=1, transient_lastDdlTime=1606338550, COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE=true, totalSize=68, numRows=3, rawDataSize=65}, viewOriginalText:null, viewExpandedText:null, tableType:MANAGED_TABLE)
```

Observation:

```
inputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat,
outputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat, compressed:false,
```

I created a parquet table directly.

```
create table parqtab2(id int) stored as parquet;
```

Detailed info is here.

```
Detailed Table Information  Table(tableName:parqtab2, dbName:dbtest, owner:cloudera, createTime:1606338696, lastAccessTime:0, retention:0, sd:StorageDescriptor(cols:[FieldSchema(name:id, type:int, comment:null)], location:hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/dbtest.db/parqtab2, inputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat, outputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat, compressed:false, numBuckets:-1, serdeInfo:SerDeInfo(name:null, serializationLib:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe, parameters:{serialization.format=1}), bucketCols:[], sortCols:[], parameters:{}, skewedInfo:SkewedInfo(skewedColNames:[], skewedColValues:[], skewedColValueLocationMaps:{}), storedAsSubDirectories:false), partitionKeys:[], parameters:{transient_lastDdlTime=1606338696}, viewOriginalText:null, viewExpandedText:null, tableType:MANAGED_TABLE)
```

Observation from the extended properties:

```
inputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat,
outputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the right syntax for the above question.

`CREATE TABLE parqtable STORED AS PARQUET AS SELECT * FROM textfiletable;`